Wrong or missing application name in ConnectionString since update to Excel 2409
I have a severe problem preventing some of my Excel sheets from working properly. Till version 2408 of Excel 365, all vba code in it worked just fine. Since the update from September (2024) to version 2409, I get this error message each time I try to connect to a PostgreSQL database:
Expression.Error: key=value argument incorrect in ConnectionString

Parametername: application name

I am not aware of using any application name in any ConnectionString. I just programmed Excel VBA so that the actual SQL string is built from cells within the workbook. How could I apply any application name in such a thing as ConnectionString, which I never knowingly used before?
I tried to locate this ConnectionString but was not successful. I also exported the rdp file but there was no application name mentioned either.
For building the connection issues: At first I established a new PostgreSQL connection by choosing a new connection to the database. Therefore I had to have the adequate drivers installed, which I did beforehand. After the different connections and queries were built, I used vba to manipulate the SQL strings within the power query expressions. For this manipulation I used the following code:
ThisWorkbook.Queries(\["SQL_string"\]) Formula = Querystring 

ThisWorkbook.Connections(9).Refresh

(where Connection(9) is the connection with the respective SQL string)

I edited your Post as it got approved "a bit too quickly" from the Staging Ground to add Formatting and remove some "noise". But you have a typo that I didn't know how to correct, you use 2 different spellings and I'm not sure which one is the correct one: Connections(9) (Plural) in your Code Block, against Connection(9) (Singular) in the sentence just after the Code Block.

I found a workaround myself. I changed the access to the database from PostGreSQL driver to ODBC und rebuilt all queries to use the new access type. So I avoided the error messages.
